# Is there a way to call a cell using a formula as the number?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m trying to create an ELO system in Google Sheets for a game I made. I need to be able to use a formulaic number:
`MATCH(L2, D:D, 0)`
To refer to a cell:
`D(MATCH(L2, D:D, 0))`
But this way doesn’t work.

I’ve tried many things, including ADDRESS, INDEX, and INDIRECT, but none of them worked.

Comment: Share few sample data and then desired output.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(L2, D:D, 0), 4, 4))
```

or:

```
=INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(L2, D:D, 0))
```

Comment: @GusS can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use OFFSET from 0,0. In this case it would be from 1,1 = A1. From there you can move as many rows or columns as needed, but substracting one:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,-1+rownumber,-1+columnnumber)
```

Change both variables for the cell value of formula you may need